# Tor Expert Running tor check fails

Tags: configuration, windows, help, torcheck

I have configured Tor to run as a Windows service, it seems to be working as it is producing logs. I have configured it to run on 9990. I have configured Firefox proxy to use it, however when I check my configuration at https://check.torproject.org, it fails and shows my actual IP. I am running Windows 10 and ESET Smart Security. I have tried running it on default port by commenting out "+SocksPort 9990" but still the same results.

Following are the log and configuration:

TORRC File:

```
DataDirectory [***Masked***]\Tor
+SocksPort 9990

UseBridges 1
Bridge obfs4 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx 8IGTG2XNP642NEQPZ3M2LLLWWKE8FL3CXOJPTRR7 cert=S29Sp2A+5YL083RFGTKADQ3GW/9S29Sp2A5YL083RFGTKADQ3GW/9S29Sp2AE5YL083RF iat-mode=0 #Example Bridge#

ClientTransportPlugin fte exec [***Masked***]\PluggableTransports\fteproxy --managed

ClientTransportPlugin obfs2,obfs3,obfs4,scramblesuit exec [***Masked***]\PluggableTransports\obfs4proxy

ClientTransportPlugin meek exec [***Masked***]\PluggableTransports\terminateprocess-buffer [***Masked***]\PluggableTransports\meek-client-torbrowser -- [***Masked***]\PluggableTransports\meek-client

GeoIPFile [***Masked***]\Tor\geoip
GeoIPv6File [***Masked***]\Tor\geoip6
Log notice file [***Masked***]\Tor\notice.log

MaxCircuitDirtiness 100
ExitNodes {gb},{us}
StrictNodes 1
```

Log File:

```
Sep 28 22:39:19.000 [notice] Got stop/shutdown request; shutting down cleanly.
Sep 28 22:41:32.000 [notice] Tor [***Masked***]ver (git-6babd3d9ba9318b3) opening log file.
Sep 28 22:41:32.148 [notice] Tor [***Masked***]ver (git-6babd3d9ba9318b3) running on Windows 8 with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2k, Zlib 1.2.8, Liblzma N/A, and Libzstd N/A.
Sep 28 22:41:32.150 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 28 22:41:32.175 [notice] Read configuration file "[***Masked***]\torrc".
Sep 28 22:41:32.182 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9990
Sep 28 22:41:32.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file [***Masked***]\geoip.
Sep 28 22:41:32.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file [***Masked***]\geoip6.
Sep 28 22:41:32.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0%: Starting
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "bridges"
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] Bridge [***Masked***]Name has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address ([***Masked***]IP:PORT) based on the configured Bridge address.
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] Bridge [***Masked***]Name has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address ([***Masked***]IP:PORT) based on the configured Bridge address.
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] Bridge [***Masked***]Name has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address ([***Masked***]IP:PORT) based on the configured Bridge address.
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (cached): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:34.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: Pluggable transport proxies still configuring
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:41:44.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network
Sep 28 22:41:44.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop
Sep 28 22:41:45.000 [notice] We'd like to launch a circuit to handle a connection, but we already have 32 general-purpose client circuits pending. Waiting until some finish.
Sep 28 22:41:46.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit
Sep 28 22:41:46.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:47.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:47.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:41:47.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:47.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:47.000 [notice] Bridge [***Masked***]Name has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address ([***Masked***]IP:PORT) based on the configured Bridge address.
Sep 28 22:41:47.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:48.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:48.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Sep 28 22:41:48.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
Sep 28 22:41:48.000 [notice] Bridge [***Masked***]Name has both an IPv4 and an IPv6 address.  Will prefer using its IPv4 address ([***Masked***]IP:PORT) based on the configured Bridge address.
Sep 28 22:41:48.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:48.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:48.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:41:49.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:49.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:49.000 [notice] new bridge descriptor [***Masked***]Name (fresh): $[***Masked***]Text~[***Masked***]Name at [***Masked***]IP
Sep 28 22:41:49.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:41:51.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:42:06.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:42:06.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:42:07.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:42:08.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:42:08.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:42:26.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:42:26.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:42:26.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:42:26.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:42:26.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:42:26.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:42:28.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:42:28.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:42:29.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:42:29.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:42:29.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect to [***Masked***]IP:PORT ("general SOCKS server failure")
Sep 28 22:43:23.000 [warn] Socks version 80 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:44:07.000 [warn] Socks version 80 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:44:07.000 [warn] Socks version 80 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:44:34.000 [warn] Socks version 67 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
Sep 28 22:44:39.000 [warn] Socks version 67 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
```

Comment: N.B. that standard firefox has situations where it *will* leak DNS requests under certain circumstances even with the proxy configured as SOCKS5 with remote lookups enabled, which Tor Browser has patches to prevent.

Comment: I was only checking if its Picking up the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not "+SocksPort 9990" but just "SocksPort 9990" - and, according to your logs - it is not fully bootstrapped yet when you're trying to use it - look for a message

```
Sep 28 22:41:48.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done
```

only after this line you can start to use Tor. And - you seem to be using it as a HTTP proxy, but it's a SOCKS one(in the latest alpha they do try to add HTTPS, but I do prefer SOCKS to prevent leaks):

```
Sep 28 22:41:39.000 [warn] Socks version 71 not recognized. (Tor is not an http proxy.)
```

Use "FoxyProxy Standart" add-on for your firefox and point all through SOCKS proxy on port 9990 *with DNS queries through the SOCKS proxy* - there's a switch or checkbox in proxy settings for it